# JQuery - If Statement div 'height' and 'scrollTop' conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm currently having a problem with a script i've created. Essentially the code works out when to activate a fixed div based on the scroll position and on the width of the window; as the divs height gets smaller for responsive viewing.

The problem with this is that it seems registers both of these at the same time, so the priority goes to the last of the two. Any help understanding why it's avoiding the statements would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="homeBannerContainer" class="homeBannerContainer">
        <div id="homeBannerContent">
            <div id="bannerBig">
                <div id="bannerBigFixed">
                    <?php echo the_field('mast_head_title');?>
                    <div id="bannerBigFixedSmall"><?php echo the_field('mast_head_subtitle');?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if (($("#homeBannerContainer").height() === 876) || ($(window).scrollTop() >= 780)){
         console.log("1 ");
         $('#headerContainer').css({background: 'url("http://yesyesdev.info/preventec/wp-content/themes/preventec/images/-homebanner.jpg")', position:'fixed', boxShadow: '5px -2px 15px #333'});
         $('body.home #click-menu .threeLines .line').addClass('lineAdapt');
         $('#headerContentLeft img').addClass('headerImageSmall');
         $('#headerContentRight').css({paddingTop: '25px'});
    } else {
         $('#headerContainer').css({background:'transparent', position:'fixed', boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px #333'});
         $('body.home #click-menu .threeLines .line').removeClass('lineAdapt');
         $('#headerContentLeft img').removeClass('headerImageSmall');
         $('#headerContentRight').css({paddingTop: '60px'});
    }


    if (($("#homeBannerContainer").height() === 440) || ($(window).scrollTop() >= 280)){
         console.log("2 ");
         $('#headerContainer').css({background: 'url("http://yesyesdev.info/preventec/wp-content/themes/preventec/images/-homebanner.jpg")', position:'fixed', boxShadow: '5px -2px 15px #333'});
         $('body.home #click-menu .threeLines .line').addClass('lineAdapt');
         $('#headerContentLeft img').addClass('headerImageSmall');
         $('#headerContentRight').css({paddingTop: '25px'});
    } else {
         $('#headerContainer').css({background:'transparent', position:'fixed', boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px #333'});
         $('body.home #click-menu .threeLines .line').removeClass('lineAdapt');
         $('#headerContentLeft img').removeClass('headerImageSmall');
         $('#headerContentRight').css({paddingTop: '60px'});
    }

});
```

Thank you

Comment: are you sure you use || instead of &&?

Comment: @bondythegreat && breaks the code all together, as far as i know || is the way to do it, correct me if i'm wrong though